# MVC4 Authorize Attribute overide; how to get passed in Roles?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, authorize-attribute

I'm trying to create my own [Authorize] Attribute so I can use my own authorize logic to have hierarchal roles.

If someone does `[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]` on a controller or action
How do I get the string "Admin" in my AuthorizeCore function?

I'm using this code:

```
public class Authorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        //authorize role logic
            if (true)
                return true;

        return false;
     }
    }
```

MVC4, .net 4.5, c#, VS 2012

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is quit a common thing that you have faced with.

This recommendation in post should work in MVC4 as it is working in MVC 3: - [ASP.NET MVC - Alternative to Role Provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4837103/1437962)

```
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        bool isAdmin;
        if(Roles.Contains("Admin"))
           isAdmin = true;

        return isAdmin ;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that Roles was the roles of the currently logged in user, and did not think it would have what was passed in with `[Authorize("Admin")]`

Comment: @user1308743, no problem, also voting the answers is good thing not to forget ;)

Comment: I was just waiting for the time limit to pass, to mark as answer and vote =)

Comment: No problem, let me know if there are any issues.

Answer (score 1):

Roles is a public property.  You should be able to do this:

```
public class Authorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {

        if(Roles.Contains("MyRole"))
           return true;

        return false;
    }
}
```

Or whatever it is that you need to do

Answer (score 0):

If you need to get the list of allowed roles, you can simply get the Roles property. It will list the string that was specified in the attribute decoration.

```
public class Authorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var allowedRoles = Roles;
    }
}
```

You can see this on the [AuthorizeAttribute definition](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/0541d027e040#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs)